# Configure jabber without writing password in plain text

Tags: security, passwords

I find jabber to be a fantastic tool, but it worries me a little that my password is written in plain text in my init file.
**Is there a way to configure my jabber login credentials without writing them in plain text?**

Just to be clear, I don't want to be asked for a password either. So the solution would need to hook into some external keyring/database or just do some encrypting to obscure the password.

Ideally, the solution would be OS independent, but my priority is getting it to work on Linux (with gnome) which is where I use jabber the most.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Emac's auth-source](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/auth.html).  You may discover that it is already wired into the default authentication of the tool your using, for example ERC uses it.  I wrote a bit about it in [this blog post](http://enthusiasm.cozy.org/archives/2014/07/auth-source-getting-my-secrets-out-of-my-emacs-init-file).

Answer (score 3):

I use [pass](http://www.passwordstore.org/) to store my passwords, and a lisp wrapper to set the value appropriately:

```
(require 's)
(defun my-password (pass)
  (s-trim (shell-command-to-string
            (concat "pass show " pass))))

(setq my-jabber-password (my-password "Personal/jabber"))
```